# .NET Core with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-core

I have seen some videos of people using other database systems with .NET Core, and wanted to use MySQL with an app I am building. I am getting an exception when I run my app after adding this line to my ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql().AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

My project.json file is mostly unchanged except for adding these packages.

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",  
"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0"
```

Here is my final project.json file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",    
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",  
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

What do I need in order for it to work correctly? In MyDbContext, I've overridden the OnConfiguring method to use my connection string.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

    => optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"Server=localhost;database=MyTestDb;uid=root;pwd=pwd;");
```

Where have I gone wrong? I get this exception as mentioned, in Startup.cs in the configure services method,

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in
>   user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: The error message explicitly tell you that assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' that was found does not match that one that loading assembly was built against. I believe you study a) where you reference this assembly (or third-party assemblies do), b) how does the assembly that is found deployed to its location and finally match one and the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your project.  You are running at 1.0.1 for your .net core version

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

Then you load other dependencies and they are at version 1.1.0

```
"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0"
```

If you are using VS 2015 you can go to the nuget package manager and go to the update tab and update all the packages that have available updates.

If you are using VS code then you have to go through them line by line and look up the package on nuget find out the latest version and update the version number then run dotnet restore from the command prompt while in the project folder.

If you haven't installed .net core version 1.1.0 it will be necessary to do that as well.

Hope this helps.